# Populate date according to month and year selected in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dropdown list each for year, month and date.
Now I want to populate my dates according to year and month selected by the user. I want to try it using normal dropdown list, so I'm ruling out the option of datetime picker for the time being.

This is my code which i'm using normally to fill the values:

```
 protected void Call_Date()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        date0.Items.Add(i.ToString());

    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
    {
        month0.Items.Add(j.ToString());

    }

    for (int k = DateTime.Now.Year; k <= 2020; k++)
    {
        year0.Items.Add(k.ToString());
    }
}
```

What can I do to make it work accordingly?

Comment: what about leap year and months with variable days?you need validation in that case

Comment: Why not use a datepicker ? i mean its there for this specific purpose.

Comment: They say that you should not invent the wheel twice in order to save precious time. If there is already a control available that actually serves you need, you should pick that. Additionally what Cris said is vital in that case, too.

Comment: @Cris: Yes. I have to check for that too.

Comment: @Syrion check the link i have posted as answer,it has sample code what you may require

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime((int)year0.SelectedValue,(int)month0.SelectedValue,(int)date0.SelectedValue)
```

But remember there is a issue that @Cris as raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the year is leap by using `DateTime.IsLeapYear` method. If you dont want to use DateTime function, then you can calculate leap year like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214019). Once that is found, then finding number of days in a month is easy.

Jan.    31,
Feb.    28/29(leap year),
Mar.    31,
Apr.    30,
May 31,
Jun.    30,
Jul.    31,
Aug.    31,
Sep.    30,
Oct.    31,
Nov.    30,
Dec.    31

Comment: you also have `DateTime.DaysInMonth` to get the days :)\

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample example for you http://dotnetstation.wordpress.com/adding-date-year-and-month-in-dropdownlist-using-aspnetc/

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the frameworks's DateTime class to get the dates that you need from the selected Year and Month.

```
    //build a date for the month and year selected by the user
    DateTime newDate = new DateTime(yearSelected, monthSelected, 1);

    //iterate through the days in that month
    for (int i = newDate.Day; i < DateTime.DaysInMonth(newDate.Year, newDate.Month); i++ )
    {
        //add to your list
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a Client-side solution would be okay, but it looks like you may be able to use Knockout as one option... It kinda looks like this example: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html, where depending on the first dropdown (Month), you can populate the next (day) and have it match up the valid amount of days so you can generate a valid date...

Having said that, I recently made an editor template for a birthdate field... It is about the same setup as you, with three dropdowns. It also has a hidden field (the actual date) that is set using Javascript that is run every time one of the three dropdownboxes changes. It then tries to set the value of the hidden field and run Unobtrusive Validation on the field to check for a valid date and show an errormessage if not...

Pseudo-code that checks the dropdowns in the editor template is here:

```
$("Dropdown").change(function () {
 if (($("Year").val() != "") && ($("Day").val() != "") && ($("Month").val() != "")) {
   var date = new Date($("Year").val(), $("Month").val() - 1, $("Day").val())
    $("Hidden").val(date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    $('form').validate().element('Hidden');
  } else {
   $("Hidden").val("");
  }
}
})
```

Lastly as Cris said, you also need to check the date for a valid date and not Feb 31th. Serverside, I would just do a Date.TryParse() on the date to check if it is an actual date and not  or something when the form gets posted...